# Влияет ли блок try на производительность кода в С++, если исключений не возникает?

Tags: c++, исключения, производительность, try-catch

Прошу прощения если я задаю глупый вопрос, но мне нужно знать точно. Если я пишу подобный код на С++:

```
int main() try {
.....
}
catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
    ...
}
...
catch (...) {
    cout << "Was throw exception" << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Будет ли скомпилированный в блоке try код отличным от такого же кода без блока try? Может ли блок try оказывать какое либо влияние на производительность помимо ситуаций когда происходят исключения?

Comment: Вообще-то формально говоря - да, так как должен поддерживать список объектов, которые при сворачивании стека удалять... но реально - не очень. А если нужно знать точно - то практику как критерий истины ((с) Маркс) еще не декоммунизировали :), так что просто проведите несколько экспериментов и посмотрите на степень влияния...

Comment: Согласно статье https://dou.ua/forums/topic/6819/ на производительности не сказывается никак. Разве что finally добавляет один переход.

Comment: @coder675 в статье про .NET CLR, я думаю что его работу с исключениями нельзя сравнивать с С++. Всё равно большое спасибо.

Comment: Механизм исключений работает на уровне машинного кода. Он как раз и придуман для того чтобы ускорить программу и не проводить перед сложными шагами дополнительную кучу проверок, а делать их после если что то пошло не так. Так что по моему нет там отличий. Это общий механизм.

Comment: @coder675 Мне всегда казалось, что в CLI система прерываний более громоздкая. Приведу пример. Вот я только что накатал пример перехвата ексепшена деления на 0.

http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=118070

Могу ли я написать такое же на С++?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/208006/ и https://habrahabr.ru/post/279111/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откровенно говоря, не очень понятно, как именно провести эксперимент... Так что это не более чем иллюстрация, по которой трудно делать выводы.

На такой функции-пустышке на VC++ 2017 попробовал -

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        muTimer mt;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                f(i);
            } catch(...)
            {}
        }
        cout << mt.stop().duration() << endl;
    }
    {
        muTimer mt;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            f(i);
        }
        cout << mt.stop().duration() << endl;
    }
}

int total;

void f(int i)
{
    total += i;
}
```

Получилось примерно 4 миллисекунды на 0.6. Но, думаю, что при серьезных функциях соотношение будет куда ближе к 1:1 :)

Comment: Я почти такой же тест писал, только в forах набил операций которые могут кидать исключения (кастовал, присваивал array, аллоцировал и vector и т.д. =)). И блоков catch поставил несколько, на бэдекаст т.п. Но у меня результаты всегда плавали и нельзя было сказать не чего конкретно. Поэтому для себя я переформулировал вопрос:
> Будет ли скомпилированный в блоке try код отличным от такого же кода без блока try?

Comment: Сам код внутри try-catch при прочих равных - вряд ли, но дополнительные накладные расходы на try-catch, думаю, будут. Впрочем, можно покопаться в ассемблерных листингах...